# Python 3- How do I compare keys in one dictionary to another, add their values, storing the result in the value of the first?

Tags: python, dictionary, key, key-value

When the value of `dict_two` appears in `dict_one`, I would like to add the corresponding values, storing them in `dict_one`, in a Pythonic way, if possible.

```
dict_one = {'rose':5,
            'daisy':5,
            'lily':5,
            'anthurium':5,
            'sunflower':5}

dict_two = {'rose':1,
            'lily':2,
            'sunflower':5}

for i in dict_two:
    if i in dict_two.keys():
        dict_one[i] += dict_two[i]

print(dict_one)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use dict comprehension like this:

```
{k: v + dict_two.get(k, 0) for k, v in dict_one.items()}
```

This returns:

```
{'rose': 6, 'daisy': 5, 'lily': 7, 'anthurium': 5, 'sunflower': 10}
```

Or if you prefer to update `dict_one` in-place:

```
dict_one.update({k: v + dict_one[k] for k, v in dict_two.items() if k in dict_one})
```

Comment: The first option is shorter and straightforward, but I do want dict_one updated 'in-place' as your second option does. Your code works, and I appreciate your help.